# How to Check which user is currently using after logged in via passport. js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I wrote a login system with passport.js
A different group of users will be routed to a different path.

```
router.post('/signin', passport.authenticate('local', {
failureRedirect: '/fail',
failureFlash: true
}),
(req, res) => {  
   //if sucess
    if (req.body.group == 'GroupA'){
        res.redirect('/groupa');
    }
    else if (req.body.group == 'GroupB') {
        res.redirect('/groupb');
    }
    else {
    res.redirect('/groupc');
    }
}
```

I can successfully go to a different route,
but I can't basically change the path on my URL to enter another route after logging in
(Eg logged in as GroupA, then type http://localhost/groupb and I can enter that route)
the "ensureAuthenticated" function I did can only check if the user logged in but not with which user, so how can I avoid such problem that user goes to others' path?
(ensureAuthenticated for preference)

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next){
if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
    console.log(req.body.username);
    return next();
}
else {
    console.log('You haven\'t login');
    res.redirect('/'); //back to login page
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If authentication succeeds, the next handler will be invoked and the **req.user** property will be set to the authenticated user.

[PassportJs authenticate](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/)

Comment: so i did the following
if(req.user.username != 'groupa') {
        res.redirect('/home'); }
but end up with error (_http_outgoing)

Comment: why should the username be the name of the group? isn't it supposed to be `req.user.group != 'groupa'` ? what error are you receiving please elaborate. how does the user object suppost to look like ?

Comment: oh im sorry, should be `req.user.group `
the error occurs on the `res.redirct('/home')`

Comment: @Xenox if you reach inside the if statement than the condition succeeded .. what are you receiving when just `console.log(req.user);` ?

Comment: i actually got the right value, i can get `groupa` from `req.user.group`, i tried to just do `console.log` in the `if(req.user.username != 'groupa)' and it works fine, so i guess i the problem of the `res.redirct`

Comment: @Xenox So the question is answered . you have another problem which deserves another question. sounds like you have a problem with the http request but you need to elaborate on the error you are receiving and what have you done to cause it.